# SAS 9.4 does not scroll Output window with new output

Tags: sas

In SAS 9.4, I am sending using the Output window with the Listing preference.  The window, however, does not automatically scroll to show new output.  For example, if I first do a proc print, the output will show up on the first page of the Output window.  If I do an additional proc print, the Output window remains on the first page and does not automatically scroll down to show the second proc print results.  There must be a preference that I am not setting correctly, but haven't figured it out.  Thanks in advance for your suggestions/solutions.

djohns

Comment: Sorry for the garbled first sentence. It should say, '..sending output to the Output window with the Listing preference (not HTML).'

Comment: You can edit your post instead of adding comments for corrections or improvements

Comment: What have you set in the output window for the settings AUTOSCROLL and AUTOPOP?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.

This problem was resolved by setting Tools->Options->Preferences->Results by checking 'Create Listing', unchecking 'Create HTML', and checking 'View Results as they are Generated'.  It seems like I did this several times.

I'm not sure that this was necessary, but I also set Tools->Options->Output->Display Autoscroll to 'PAGE', and checked 'PAGE MODE'.

Now when I do a Proc, the output goes to the Output window and the Output window pops to the front showing the page with the latest output.